# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.SqlNode cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Im trying to update a record with a *HQL* query but I am getting a `CastException`.
If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it.
I have checked the Internet for a while now but I cant find any information on this.
Please let me know if you have more information on this exception.

The full error message its returning:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.SqlNode cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.generateSyntheticDotNodeForNonQualifiedPropertyRef(HqlSqlWalker.java:495)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.lookupNonQualifiedProperty(HqlSqlWalker.java:488)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.propertyRef(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1102)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.assignment(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1008)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.setClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:729)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.updateStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:349)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:228)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:160)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
        at Database.HibernateConnection.updateFlight(HibernateConnection.java:161)
        at Controller.Controller.ChangeFlight(Controller.java:527)
        at View.CreateChangeFlightView.btnSaveActionPerformed(CreateChangeFlightView.java:738)
        at View.CreateChangeFlightView.access$1000(CreateChangeFlightView.java:45)
        at View.CreateChangeFlightView$6.actionPerformed(CreateChangeFlightView.java:299)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6263)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

query: deleted

Comment: When this occurs in some sort of distributed package (vs your own code) it usually means that there's a mismatch in the JAR files that are being used to support the package.  In this case, likely one of the two classes mentioned is in a JAR file that is at the wrong version level, or the two involved classes are referencing such incompatible classes from elsewhere.  (Of course, it can also be a plain old code bug, depending on how well tested the package is.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. I edited the query in my start post.

Comment: I also have 4 other hql update querys that work fine. Its just this one that is throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by the fact that `from` is a reserved word in HQL. Since it's not possbile to escape a keyword in HQL, the only possbile solution is to rename that field.

Comment: Oh thanks man. Ill try to rename the to field in the morning. i really appreciate your help. This really made me clueless.

Comment: I had the same problem with using a rerserved word (order) as an alias. I used another alias and I didn't get the ClassCastException anymore.

Comment: can you paste code here.i did not understand that you said

Comment: Same case here as the one mentioned axtavt but with the keyword "group" for Oracle db.