# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SqlNode cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql, reserved-words

I am trying to execute a select statement in JPA which is throwing me the above error. The code is:

```
TypedQuery<ListPersonsObj> typedQuery = null;
String query = "";
List<ListPersonsObj> list = null;
if (some condition) {
   query = "SELECT NEW in.healthelife.DGS.dao.ListPersonsObj"
                    + "(c.personId, c.givenName, c.middleName, c.address1, "
                    + "c.address2, c.dateOfBirth, "
                    + "c.phoneNumber, c.email) FROM Patients c";
   typedQuery = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager()
                   .createQuery(query, ListPersonsObj.class);
   list = typedQuery.getResultList();
}
```

The ListPersonsObj class:

```
public class ListPersonsObj {

   private Long personId;
   private String givenName;
   private String middleName;
   private String address1;
   private String address2;
   private String dateOfBirth;
   private String phoneNumber;
   private String email;

   public ListPersonsObj() {
   }

   public ListPersonsObj(Long personId, String givenName, String middleName,
         String address1, String address2,
         String dateOfBirth, String phoneNumber, String email) {
      this.personId = personId;
      this.givenName = givenName;
      this.middleName = middleName;
      this.address1 = address1;
      this.address2 = address2;
      this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
      this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
      this.email = email;
   }

   public ListPersonsObj(ListPersonsObj list) {
      try {
         BeanUtils.copyProperties(this, list);
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   // .. getters & setters 
}
```

Exception caught

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SqlNode cannot be cast to
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode

Can anyone please shed some light on this.

Comment: Give the whole exception stack trace and comment line numbers in to code where it happens.

Comment: @pirho The problem is in package name (in.healthelife.*). I have changed it to com.healthelife and now it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One reason for this happening is that Hibernate finds a reserved word in a wrong place in JPQL.

For this case

> The problem is with package name
>
> ...
>
> The prefix is 'in' instead of 'com'. While parsing the query the 'in' is treated as reserved world

For reference, [see this](https://coderanch.com/t/606480/databases/Hibernate-scalar-queries-constructor-expression)

Related issue in Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716729/java-lang-classcastexception-org-hibernate-hql-ast-tree-sqlnode-cannot-be-cast)

Comment: Yeah, I found out just a while ago. Thanks for the reply though. I have changed the package name and it works!